# Selecting a record created moments before returns nothing

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a function in Lambda that reserves a row in a table in MySQL and a separate one that loads a row from the same table.

My RDS environment has only a writer instance, no readers or any other replication set.

I call the first (writer) function and I get back the primary key of the new record as expected. I can call it repeatedly and get back new primary keys. I look at the data in the table and I see them all there.

But then I call the other (reader) function to load one of those rows and get nothing back. No matter how long I wait between calling the writer and reader functions the reader always comes back with nothing for the record. If I deploy an update to the reader function then make a request for one of the previously generated rows I get the data back as expected.

It's like the database connection made in the reader is not accepting that there is new information in the database it's reading from. It makes no sense to me since the data clearly exists. I'm not sure if this is a Lambda issue or something I'm not doing right in Python.

Any idea what's going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: It sounds like the "reader" function has a transaction running (or autocommit disabled), blocking it from seeing changes from more recent transactions (depending on your isolation level) but there's not really enough info here to prove or disprove that, but it's certainly consistent, if the reader function holds onto a db connection between invocations.

Comment: I didn't set anything up to disable implicit commits and haven't had this issue with anything else. And despite not using transactions I am executing a connection.commit() after every insert/update. I haven't changed anything but today it's working fine. I have no idea why it started acting like this yesterday but that's concerning that it happened at all. It only happened in my TEST environment so I really hope this doesn't crop up in PROD too. I have no idea how to even troubleshoot this.